# Trying to add the Information emoji to webpage

Tags: html

I'm trying to add the white i on blue button information emoji to a webpage and I'm only seeing the i on a white background. Hoping someone can help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset=“UTF-8”>
</head>
<body>
    
<p>For more information <a href="faqs.html#faq5">&#x2139;</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check whether the character encoding is set to UTF-8 or not

Comment: I've edit my post and added the full test code @JoyDey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the meta charset on the top. Don't forget to include that. Also from your question it seems like you missed the color style. Here's the full code

```css
a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #00a6ed;
  width: 2.5rem;
  height: 2.5rem;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  border-radius: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="../css/global_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <meta charset=“UTF-8”>
</head>

<body>
  <p><a href="faqs.html#faq5">i</a></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's still not what I'm trying to achieve @JoyDey.  I'm trying to have the white i on a blue button as shown for the information emoji 1523 on here https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html or is the idea that I have to create my own button?

Comment: I have updated the code based on what you wanted. This could have been replicated easily without using emoji.

Comment: Oh that is exactly what I thought the emoji would look like. Thank you @JoyDey.  How would it be done without emoji?

Comment: You can style is using CSS like I did or you can use tools like Figma to make an svg or use some kind of iconfonts like https://fontawesome.com.

Comment: I used your suggested snippet but because I have other links on the page that need a different ink format I've changed it however doing this the "i" goes to black.  Can you see what I am doing wrong here?  

    a.info:link {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #00a6ed;
    width: 1.2rem;
    height: 1.2rem;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    border-radius: .2rem;
  }

Comment: remove :link from `a.info`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242756/discussion-between-joy-dey-and-bmuu).